# How to display sum of numbers divided by their factorial?

Tags: c, factorial

I'm a beginner and I am having a really hard time while doing this program.
The question is:

```
(1/1!)+(2/2!)+(3/3!)+(4/4!)- - - -n
```

So here are the n number of terms(in which a number is divided by its factorial) and I have to display the output of the sum of any number of terms which are given in scanf function.

Only one thing I know is that this program can be done by using "Nested for" loop but I haven't perfect grip yet on C language. So you guys have to have help me out in this. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main(void){
    int s,a,b,n,fact=1;
    //clrscr();
    printf("Enter number of terms=");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(a=1;a<=n;a++) {
        fact=fact*a;
        b=(a/fact);
        printf("Sum=%d",s);
    }
    getche();
}
```

P.S It's must for me to do it with "Nested for" loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: Decompose your program into smaller parts. If you know what a function is, write a function that compuiters the factorial of a number, Once that works, all you need is a 3 or 4 lines of c in a single loop.

Comment: @souravghosh Thanks man, I will take care of the rules before posting next time. I am really sorry for my mistakes.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks! I hope your method will work out for me.

Comment: You have already written some code, but did not bother to post it in your question.  You had a firm 'must use nested loops' constraint in your assigment, but didn't bother to tell us in your question.  'you guys have to have help me out in this' - why?  You didn't help us any.  In fact, by witholding information, you wasted rakeb's time:((

Comment: `(1/1!)+(2/2!)+(3/3!)+(4/4!)` ==> `1+(1/1!)+(1/2!)+(1/3!)+...+(1/(n-1)!)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int n;
    float sum = 0,d,fact =1,j,i;
    printf("Enter the number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        fact = 1;
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            fact = fact * j;
        }

        d =  (float) i / (float) fact ;

        sum = sum  + d;

    }

  printf("sum = %f", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Its working ..you can check over here :-https://ideone.com/JVXQVX

Comment: Glad it's working for me. I am really grateful for your dedication in making a working program for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

No you do not need any *Nested for loops* to solve your problem. Here's a procedure you may follow:

```
function factorial
    Input: numbers L.
    Output: factorial of L.

function sum
    Input: n.
    Output: sum.

sum = 0;
for i = 1 to n, do
   sum ← sum + (i / factorial(i))
return sum
```

Comment: I am actually being instructed by my teacher to do it with nested for loop.
Here is the program I have written but it doesn't display fractional part in the output.
`code`
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(void)
{
int s,a,b,n,fact=1;
clrscr();
printf("Enter number of terms=");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(a=1;a<=n;a++)
{
fact=fact*a;
b=(a/fact);
printf("Sum=%d",s);
}
getche();
}
`code`

Comment: Tell your teacher you find another better approach!

Comment: I will but can you you please help me for now? I have to submit work today. Thanks! :)

Comment: [sigh] Summary: ' @rakeb.void was kind enough to help by demonstrating a good design, whereupon I added a new constraint that made his effort a waste'.   I hope you fail your course:(

Comment: @MartinJames Your's last sentence "I hope you fail your course", this made me extremely disappointed. I never expected this type of statement from very senior guys. Think before you say bad words for others.

Comment: @abhanan93, you accidentally misunderstood what Martin James said. You came to stackoverflow at last moment with an ambiguous presentation of your problem. Look, we solve problems here for free because we love our community, so _I hope you fail your course_ is a metaphor reminding you never do that again. I think  Martin James successfully failed this time.

Comment: @rakeb.void I am sorry for my misunderstanding Martin's comment. And I am really thankful for your efforts that you made a program for me. :) I hope that I will make a good thread next time without bothering anyone. :)